# Using defer with pointers

Tags: go

Let us say that I have the following code:

```
func getConnection(fileName string) *os.File {
    file, err := os.Open(fileName)
    //Check for error
    return file
}
```

I use this function to open a file and the function is called from another function that does some other activity.

My question is, now that I have opened the file, how do I close it. If I were to add `defer file.Close()` inside `getConnection()`, wouldn't it close the file before returning? Does it make sense to use defer inside the calling function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the purpose of your function is to return a file, why would you want to close it in the function that returns it?

In this case it is the responsibility of the *caller* to properly close the file, preferably with `defer`:

```
func usingGetConnection() {
    f := getConnection("file.txt")
    defer f.Close()
    // Use f here
}
```

Although your `getConnection()` function swallows errors, you should use multi-return value to indicate problems like this:

```
func getConnection(fileName string) (*os.File, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(fileName)
    //Check for error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return file, nil
}
```

And using it:

```
func usingGetConnection() {
    f, err := getConnection("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // Handle err somehow
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // Use f here
}
```